# "Unable to determine the location of Tomcat" cmd message

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, cmd

I'm working on a school project, about web apps with servlets, running on tomcat etc. This morning, without an apparent reason i try to start tomcat from `C:\jakarta-tomcat-3.3.2\bin` "startup" but the cmd opens up for a millisecond showing

```
Unable to determine the location of Tomcat and closes again.
```

I had set it up and it was working fine up until now!! I have tried to restore the system to a previous point, but it only got worse, the paths were gone and messed up. I googled the cmd message, but shockingly it did not spawned any relevant responses.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you can take a look inside the startup script to understand what location is being searched for. You will most likely find that either `startup.bat` or `catalina.bat` is attempting to use a variable that is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `service tomcat6 start`

Read more here: https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Server/2/html/Installation_Guide/start_stop_tomcat-ZIP.html

Answer (score 0):

Set CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE as system variables and point them at your Tomcat directory.